# How to modify a json object?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the `src` from an `img` tag?  I have an object that I need to remove image tag value example

**Input is this**

```
[

    {
        "N": "ABC corp",
        "a": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "c": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "r": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_green.gif\" alt=\"green\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "p": "<img src=\"https://a.na7.visual.force.com/resource/1260007793000/a/iconset/gray.gif\" alt=\" \" height=\"16\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\"/>"

    }
]
```

**The output that I want is this**

```
[
    {
        "N": "3M",
        "a": "red",
        "c": "red",
        "r": "red",
        "p": "gray"

    },

    {
        "N": "ABC corp",
        "a": "red",
        "c": "red",
        "r": "green",
        "p": "gray"

    }
]
```

How can I create this new object from the given input object if it the property value that I want is in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag?  I need to check the **src** attribute of the `img` tag in the input object properties.  If it is **flag_red.gif** then the value in the output object should be **red**.  If it is **flag_green.gif** then the value in the output object should be **green**.  If it is **gray.gif** then the value in the output object should be **grey**.

Comment: please comment  if I am wrong ..!!

Comment: Maybe you make at least some ***little*** efforts so as not to make your question look like crap? And, of course, what have you tried?

Comment: well I certainly haven't downvoted.. but can you share what you have tried!!

Comment: You haven't improved the question, but made it more unclear. Also, a close vote is incoming. From me.

Comment: I gave the link of fiddle and tried it ..i am able to get keys of object .but i did not able to get value from that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skmL2kmy/

Comment: with current code and available things, best would be to create an array of all possible color values. Check if value starts with "<img" and contains one of the colors then replace it with the color . (RegEx approach doesnt seem to be effective for this one)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following shows you how to modify your data relying on the `alt` attributes of the image tags, giving you the general idea. With little effort you can easily modify this to use the `src` attribute with modifications instead.

```
var data = [{
    "N": "3M",
        "a": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "c": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "r": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "p": "<img src=\"https://a.na7.visual.force.com/resource/1260007793000/a/iconset/gray.gif\" alt=\" \" height=\"16\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\"/>"

}, {
    "N": "ABC corp",
        "a": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "c": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "r": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_green.gif\" alt=\"green\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
        "p": "<img src=\"https://a.na7.visual.force.com/resource/1260007793000/a/iconset/gray.gif\" alt=\" \" height=\"16\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\"/>"

}];

var modified = data.reduce(function (outArr, entry) {
    var outObj = {};
    for (key in entry) {
        if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var item = entry[key];
            var node = document.createElement("div");
            node.innerHTML = item;
            var img = node.querySelector("img");
            outObj[key] = img ? img.alt : item;
        }
    }
    outArr.push(outObj);
    return outArr;
}, []); //[{"N":"3M","a":"red","c":"red","r":"red","p":" "},{"N":"ABC corp","a":"red","c":"red","r":"green","p":" "}]
```

Comment: The gray.gif example he has would not work with this answer.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter I see you didn't bother reading the text leading up to the code.

Comment: Even with the `src` attribute, this would not work. gray.gif has no "flag_" prefix

Comment: @JohnCarpenter So? It's trivial to write a regex that extracts only the file name and removes a part of it, if the said part exists: `"img/samples/flag_red.gif".replace(/.*\/|flag_|\.gif/g,'')`.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to check for `<img>` tag and if it is matching then take `substring` to get the file name and set it back to the `JSON`.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K08cSaEwsKHqVYVsCRPK?p=preview)

```
var obj=[
{
    "N": "3M",
    "a": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
    "c": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
    "r": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>"
},
{
    "N": "ABC corp",
    "a": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
    "c": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>",
    "r": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_green.gif\" alt=\"green\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>"
}
];

for(var k in obj){
    for (name in obj[k]) {
        if(obj[k][name].indexOf("<img") != -1) {
            // I have made logic based on "flag_", this can be change as per your requirement.
            var src= obj[k][name].substring(obj[k][name].indexOf("flag_")+5,obj[k][name].indexOf(".gif"));
            obj[k][name]=src;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A random string might just as well contain _"<img"_, it doesn't mean it's an image tag.